# How do I display a large black rectangle with a moveable transparent circle in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

That question wasn't very clear.

Essentially, I am trying to make a multi-player Pac-Man game whereby the players (when playing as ghosts) can only see a certain radius around them. My best guess for going about this is to have a rectangle which covers the whole maze and then somehow cut out a circle which will be centred on the ghost's rect. However, I am not sure how to do this last part in pygame.

I'd just like to add if it's even possible in pygame, it would be ideal for the circle to be pixelated and not a smooth circle, but this is not essential.

Any suggestions? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to show the scene inside a circular area, then you can do the following:

- Clear the display.
- Limit the drawing region to a **square** area around the circular area
- Draw the scene
- Draw a transparent circle surface on top of the square area

The circle surface can be created with ease on runtime. Define the radius of the circular area (`areaRadius`). Create a square [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the doubled radius of the circular area. Fill it with opaque black and draw a transparent circle in the middle:

```py
circularArea = pygame.Surface((areaRadius*2, areaRadius*2), pygame.SRCALPHA)
circularArea.fill((0, 0, 0, 255))
pygame.draw.circle(circularArea, (0,0,0,0), (areaRadius, areaRadius), areaRadius)
```

The drawing region of a surface can be limited by [`.set_clip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_clip). Calling the function with the parameter `None` removes the clipping area. In the following `screen` is the surface which represents the window and `areaCenter` is the center of the circular area on the screen:

```py
while run:

    # [...]

    # remove clipping region and clear the entire screen
    screen.set_clip(None)
    screen.fill(0)

    # set the clipping region to square around the circular area
    areaTopleft = (areaCenter[0]-areaRadius, areaCenter[1]-areaRadius)
    clipRect = pygame.Rect(areaTopleft, (areaRadius*2, areaRadius*2))
    screen.set_clip(clipRect)

    # draw the scene
    # [...]

    # draw the transparent circle on top of the rectangular clipping region
    screen.blit(circularArea, areaTopleft)  

    # clear the dripping region and draw all the things which should be visible in any case
    screen.set_clip(None)
    # [...]

    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is kind of a hack.  Build an image outside pygame that is mostly black with a circle of zero-alpha in the center, then blit that object on top of your ghost character to only see a circle around it.  I hope there is a better way but I do not know what that is.

Comment: Good idea, I’ll give it a go tonight and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Definitely does the job! Thanks for the idea, I'll leave it unanswered for now just in case pygame supports cutting shapes out of others with some command I'm not aware of yet.